# Completeness of mixed-norm space

Tags: real-analysis

This question may be simple but I need some hint or help...
For example,
if we define the norm of a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as
$\| f \|_{L^q_y L^p_x}
:= \left( \int (\int |f(x,y)|^p dx)^\frac{q}{p} dy \right)^\frac{1}{q}$,
and define $X$ to be the space as
$X := \{ f: \| f \|_{L^q_y L^p_x} < \infty \}$.
Then how to show that this is a complete normed space?
Assuming that we already know $L^p$ is a complete normed space.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you already know you must show that Cauchy sequences converge, right? Because that's all I know. I've never seen such a norm. Ha!

Comment: @The Count Yes, I wonder how to show that every Cauchy sequence converges in $X$. Is there an easy way to utilize the completeness of $L^p$ to prove it?